# Add a query to Retrofit only if value exist

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to make an endpoint which can call to:

```
...retailer/home
```

or

```
...retailer/home?uid=123123123
```

I use the next source code to generate de call:

```
@GET("retailer/home")
fun retrieveHomeContent(@Query("uid") uid: String? = null): Single<HomeContentEntity>
```

But when I test this, the result is:

```
retailer/home?uid=
```

So, I don't know how to makes retrofit to ignores the Query when the value is null. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `@QueryMap` instead of `@Query` and pass it empty if you don't want to have any query key/parameters

Answer (score 0):

@Query params support optional fields. Simply pass null if you don't want to pass a value.